# How does Gordon see?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

A friend of mine teased me that Gordon sees like Neo sees code or at least like blind Neo in the machine city (Note: Here, Neo is from Matrix and this sentence isn't part of the question, so I am not mixing canons).

It got me wondering how he really perceives the world. He is able to see everything around him and beyond for sure. But, how does it look like?

I know the TV show hasn't displayed anything from his perspective yet. Anything from comics?

Comment: His character is not directly from the comics, so nothing will be truly accurate. He is somewhat similar to [Reader](http://marvel.wikia.com/Reader_%28Inhuman%29_%28Earth-616%29), but there's been no instances of us seeing what Reader "sees", as far as I'm aware. Reader has a seeing eye dog, so I'm not entirely sure he *does* see anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Gordon is a creation of the show, and we don't yet understand how he perceives the world.**

The closest thing in the comics - indeed, apparently the inspiration for the character of Gordon - is the Inhuman called "[**Reader**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Reader_(Inhuman)_(Earth-616))":

[image]

When Reader was exposed to the Terrigen Mists, he gained the ability to make anything he reads appear in reality. The other Inhumans felt that he was too powerful, and opted to blind him so that he could never read again. Reader was actually blind at that point, and ended up with a faithful canine companion that acted as his seeing-eye-dog.

Afterwards, Reader chose to travel the world and find new Inhumans, sending them to [Attilan](http://marvel.wikia.com/Attilan) for training & safety. He could not teleport, nor did he have the obvious deformity that we see with Gordon. To the unsuspecting, he appeared to be simply a blind human.

---

Obviously, some of these elements were used for Gordon (no eyes, the role of finding new Inhumans and bringing them to the Attilan sanctuary). Gordon, however, can teleport and appears to be able to see despite his lack of eyes.